# Window.Current.Activate() results in "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a
>   different thread.

error on line **"Window.Current.Activate();"** when press **"windows"** button on my phone (suspend application), and then start it again from application list. If I press **"windows"** button, and then **"back"** button to return to the app - no problem.
Also, I do not have problems running the application for the first time.

If the application fails to resume after start button, next time it starts from scratch and works fine, until i press "windows" and then try to start the app again.

I also tried:

```
var disp = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
disp.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            Window.Current.Activate());
```

then the app fails to resume, although the error does not occur. 
What I do in the app:
I have a stackpanel, and I add elements to it by **c#** code. That part I also tried with dispatcher, but it did not help.

I also read/write files asynchronously. May be that helps too.

If you can help me to simply close the application instead of suspending, although it is not the best solution, it would still help me. Thanks!

Update:
Here is the full code of the function:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Не повторяйте инициализацию приложения, если в окне уже имеется содержимое,
        // только обеспечьте активность окна
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Создание фрейма, который станет контекстом навигации, и переход к первой странице
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            // TODO: Измените это значение на размер кэша, подходящий для вашего приложения
            rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

            // Задайте язык по умолчанию
            rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Загрузить состояние из ранее приостановленного приложения
            }

            // Размещение фрейма в текущем окне
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Удаляет турникетную навигацию для запуска.
            if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
            {
                this.transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                {
                    this.transitions.Add(c);
                }
            }

            rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;

            // Если стек навигации не восстанавливается для перехода к первой странице,
            // настройка новой страницы путем передачи необходимой информации в качестве параметра
            // навигации
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        // Обеспечение активности текущего окна
        //if (e.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
        //Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => messageList.Add(read)));
        //var disp = Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
        var disp = Window.Current.Dispatcher; 
        disp.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            Window.Current.Activate());
    }
```

Comment: Try `var disp = Window.Current.Dispatcher;`

Comment: Same effect :( no errors, but the application stopped.

Comment: no errors, but the application stopped? No exception? and application crash?

Comment: Can you post the entire activation code? Asking for a Dispatcher from the MTA won't work (it doesn't have a dispatcher, so you'll crash for different reasons).

Comment: updated with full code.

Comment: yes, it stops, no exceptions, no anything.

Comment: Can this happen because of adding elements to stackpanel programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the full code into a new pivot project (previously i started a blank windows phone project). Now it works, although I did not change anything.

Thank you all for your help!